# Проблемы с битриксом и сервером

Tags: php, битрикс, vps

Здравствуйте! Была поставленна задача перенести домен с .com на .ru. Также не оплачен битрикс с 14 года) ISP также не заполнено, конфигурация сервера выполнялась из-под консоли, как только начал вносить записи в пустую ISP и все пошло далеко в лес. error_log от апача

```
[Mon Dec 11 00:01:02 2017] [error] [client 141.8.132.35] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 00:01:06 2017] [error] [client 141.8.132.35] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 00:43:54 2017] [error] [client 181.48.9.82] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 05:56:51 2017] [error] [client 207.46.13.128] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 08:01:49 2017] [error] [client 157.55.39.22] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 08:01:51 2017] [error] [client 157.55.39.22] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 08:10:17 2017] [error] [client 40.77.167.42] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 09:26:31 2017] [error] [client 139.162.116.133] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 11:14:49 2017] [error] [client 157.55.39.95] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 11:19:58 2017] [error] [client 207.46.13.128] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 14:22:52 2017] [error] [client 164.52.7.131] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 14:47:24 2017] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Dec 11 14:47:28 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:47:28 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 11 14:48:30 2017] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Dec 11 14:48:31 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:48:31 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 11 14:54:57 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:03 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:03 2017] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:09 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:09 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 11 14:57:00 2017] [error] [client 95.161.153.62] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 14:57:01 2017] [error] [client 95.161.153.62] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs, referer: https://109.120.136.198/var/www/ludacha/data/www/ludacha.com
[Mon Dec 11 14:57:05 2017] [error] [client 95.161.153.62] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:15 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:16 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:16 2017] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:17 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:17 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Ошибки в диагностике домена из-под ISP

```
    Search for domain registration information: [ OK ]
Receive domain name servers: [ OK ]
Name servers: ns2.infobox.org, ns1.infobox.org, ns3.infobox.org, ns4.infobox.org
Lookup IP address information (ns2.infobox.org): [ OK ]
Lookup IP address information (ns1.infobox.org): [ OK ]
Lookup IP address information (ns3.infobox.org): [ OK ]
Lookup IP address information (ns4.infobox.org): [ OK ]
IP address: 109.120.136.198
Receive virtual host configuration: [ OK ]
Virtual host IP address: 109.120.136.198, 
HTTP(S) Request (http://ludacha.ru): [FAIL]
Troubleshooting finished.
```

Хотя записи в домене не менял у регистратора, только добавил в ISP
По бэкапам:
Есть файлы сайта такие -   http://joxi.ru/KAxBdKVT4j76vm
Такие - http://joxi.ru/p27a6GOi0YeqJr
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема? Связей с прошлым веб-мастером нет.
Какой стек проблем с которыми предстоит преодолеть?
Возможно поможет переустановка сервера под битрикс и стандартный билд после накатить файлы из скрина  http://joxi.ru/KAxBdKVT4j76vm, это возможно? В каком направлении копать?)
.htaccess

```
    Options -Indexes 
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
      php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

      #php_value display_errors 1

      #php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
      #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
      RewriteRule (.*) http://ludacha.ru/$1/ [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ludacha.ru [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ludacha.ru/$1 [L,R=301]

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (.*)/index\.php\ HTTP/
      RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://ludacha.ru/$1 [L,R=301]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
      RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: как минимум в версии php. версия 5.3 уже давно не поддерживается даже битриксом это раз. второе - у Вас проблема не с Битриксом а настройкой сервера на определение нового доменного имени. копать надо в этом направлении. пока что ни одна из ошибок Битрикс не затрагивает.

Comment: @NikolajSarry Поправил значение диагностики домена, поправил конфигурации. Сейчас сайт http://joxi.ru/V2VbRlaT0D9e52

Comment: Первый вопрос: зачем вы вообще полезли переносить сайт на другой хостинг? Можно просто подключить новый домен, добавить записи в админке битрикса и всё.
В остальном какой-то поток сознания. Какая разница, что у вас на сервере, если домен не делегируется?